# Return value from array

Tags: arrays, php-5.3

I have a function that returns an array and I'm trying to call a certain value from it like so

```
echo $this->getName()['first']. ' ' .$this->getName()['last'];
```

getName function...

```
protected function getName(){
    return $this->user;
}
```

the array is laid out like so...

```
$this->user = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'first' => $fn,
    'last' => $ln
);
```

This works on localhost but not on my production server. I'm guessing it has something to do with my php.ini but not sure. Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you check the production server's php version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is tagged PHP 5.3, but this syntax is only valid in 5.4.

[Look here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Also, if you develop on a Mac, please be aware that OSX Mavericks upgraded the local version of PHP from 5.3 to 5.4.

Cheers

Comment: That's what I figured it was as I was putting the PHP 5.3 tag on there but thought I would continue with the post anyway.

Comment: So, versioning turned out to be the issue?

Comment: Yup, versioning is the issue here. I need a better host :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to look at is the PHP version your production server is using. Maybe your production server is using an old PHP version.

On a side note, why would you call the same function twice? I mean, why not doing something like

```
$user = $this->getName();
echo $user['first'] . " " . $user['last'];
```